# Call button in Power Apps to make PSTN calls via Teams client on mobile

Tags: ios, mobile, microsoft-teams, powerapps

I am building a mobile Power App with an address book page. I have created a call button on this page to make phone calls using Microsoft Teams.

Here is the code I'm using: Launch("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=4:MobileNumber")

When I click the button it redirects me to Teams to make the call. The problem I'm facing is the number displayed is incorrect.

For example, when I try and call the following number:

[Mobile Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te8dz.png)

This is what it shows on Teams:

[Shows Wrong Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2S9w.png)

I have tried typing in the number manually, for example: Launch("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=4:02073307500") which works, see below:

[Correct Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW2iE.png)

The only problem is the number changes based on the gallery I'm using which pulls the data from: Office365Outlook.ContactGetItemsV2("Contacts").value

So when I use MobileNumber value, which is a field that displays the phone number, it doesn't match the number when I click the call button.

I am stuck, please help!

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Could you please share which document are you referring for this?

Comment: I am using a SharePoint list and Office 365 outlook contacts as my data source. The field reference is 'ThisItem.mobilePhone' that displays the mobile number which I have linked the call button to

Comment: Could you please refer below doc if its help you in any way.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/teams/integrate-calls-and-meetings?msclkid=89e06e17cfa711ecb9d09f4041e3f0dc

Comment: Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or are you still looking for any help?